# How to use API created by python in C ++ node

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
We are programming a pick-and-place work using the gripper of the robot arm. The program for opening and closing the purchased gripper is created by Python API, but I would like to use it in a C ++ node. Could you please tell me the easiest way to use the Python API in C ++?
A program for opening and closing the gripper is attached.
I want to use set_encorder () below in a C ++ node.
Thank you

```
import logging
import sys

from pymycobot.log import setup_logging
from pymycobot.error import check_datas
from pymycobot.common import Command, DataProcessor

class MycobotCommandGenerater(DataProcessor):

    """MyCobot Python API (Chain operation: *)

    Supported methods:


        # JOG mode and operation
  
            set_encoder()

    """

    def __init__(self, debug=False):
        """
        Args:
            port     : port string
            baudrate : baud rate string, default '115200'
            timeout  : default 0.1
            debug    : whether show debug info
        """
        self._version = sys.version_info[:2][0]
        self.debug = debug
        setup_logging(self.debug)
        self.log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    def _mesg(self, genre, *args, **kwargs):
        """

        Args:
            genre: command type (Command)
            *args: other data.
                   It is converted to octal by default.
                   If the data needs to be encapsulated into hexadecimal,
                   the array is used to include them. (Data cannot be nested)
            **kwargs: support `has_reply`
                has_reply: Whether there is a return value to accept.
        """
        command_data = self._process_data_command(args)

        LEN = len(command_data) + 2
        command = [
            Command.HEADER,
            Command.HEADER,
            LEN,
            genre,
            command_data,
            Command.FOOTER,
        ]

        real_command = self._flatten(command)
        has_reply = kwargs.get("has_reply", False)

        return real_command, has_reply



    # JOG mode and operation
 
     def set_encoder(self, joint_id, encoder):
        """Set joint encoder value.

        Args:
            joint_id: Joint id 1 - 7
            encoder: The value of the set encoder.
        """
        return self._mesg(Command.SET_ENCODER, joint_id, [encoder])

    def get_encoder(self, joint_id):
        """Get servo encoder

        Args:
            joint_id (int): servo number.

        Returns:
            (int16): servo encoder value.
        """
        return self._mesg(Command.GET_ENCODER, joint_id, has_reply=True)

    def set_encoders(self, encoders, sp):
        """Set all servo encoder.

        Args:
            encoders (list): encoder list
            sp (int): speed

        Returns:
            (str): command.
        """
        return self._mesg(Command.SET_ENCODERS, encoders, sp)

    def get_encoders(self):
        return self._mesg(Command.GET_ENCODERS, has_reply=True)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390611/how-to-use-api-created-by-python-in-c-++-node/) by [yo4hi6o](https://answers.ros.org/users/73294/yo4hi6o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2021-11-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-11**:
What about creating a stand-alone Python node which wraps the example you show here? Then create a couple of services (open/close gripper) and invoke those services from your C++ node.

**Comment by [yo4hi6o](https://answers.ros.org/users/73294/yo4hi6o/) on 2021-11-11**:
@gvdhoorn thank you for your quick response. Do you know a git project created that way or a helpful article?I'm learning python and I'm not used to it yet. thank you.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-11**:
The [Writing a Simple Service and Client (Python)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29) page shows how to create a simple server and client using `rospy`. Once you complete that, you can probably extend it to make a server for your services. The client would be on the C++ side, just as any other regular `roscpp` service clients.

**Comment by [yo4hi6o](https://answers.ros.org/users/73294/yo4hi6o/) on 2021-11-11**:
@gvdhoorn
thank you.
I'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Doesn't [elephantrobotics/mycobot_ros](https://github.com/elephantrobotics/mycobot_ros) already provide ROS nodes? [This node](https://github.com/elephantrobotics/mycobot_ros/blob/0db51867ed9c2c6910407fa61e7a17b1b0986ee7/mycobot_communication/scripts/mycobot_services.py#L26) even seems to have a "gripper" service.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yo4hi6o](https://answers.ros.org/users/73294/yo4hi6o/) on 2021-11-11**:
@gvdhoorn Thank you, I just noticed it. I will use that. Thank you

**Comment by [yo4hi6o](https://answers.ros.org/users/73294/yo4hi6o/) on 2021-11-14**:
@Using the service server provided by elephantrobotics, which you mentioned. I was able to make it work. I was able to learn one more.
Thank you very much.